# ASP.NET Healthchecks Not Working on Blazor App Deployment

Tags: c#, asp.net, blazor, health-check

I have built a Blazor server app and deployed it on IIS. All of its core functionality is running as expected aside from the healthchecks. When I run the Blazor app via visual studio, I get the following results in my healthcheck-ui:

[image]

However, when i go to the healthchecks ui page on the deployed app this is what i see:

[image]

As you can see the status is unhealthy, the sql health check has 'disappeared' and the endpoint health check seemingly has a different name?
Below is my **Startup.cs**:

```
using AjuaBlazorServerApp.HealthChecks;
using HealthChecks.UI.Client;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.HealthChecks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Diagnostics.HealthChecks;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace AjuaBlazorServerApp
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddRazorPages();
            services.AddServerSideBlazor();
            services.AddHostedService<PeriodicExecutor>();
            services.AddHealthChecks()
            .AddCheck<AjuaEndpointHealth>("AjuaEndpoint",null) 
            .AddSqlServer(Configuration["sqlString"],
                healthQuery: "select 1",
                failureStatus: HealthStatus.Degraded,
                name: "SQL Server");
            services.AddHealthChecksUI(opt =>
            {
                opt.SetEvaluationTimeInSeconds(5); //time in seconds between check    
                opt.MaximumHistoryEntriesPerEndpoint(60); //maximum history of checks    
                opt.SetApiMaxActiveRequests(1); //api requests concurrency    
                opt.AddHealthCheckEndpoint("Ajua API", "/health"); //map health check api    
            }).AddInMemoryStorage();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            loggerFactory.AddLog4Net("log4net.config");
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            }

            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
                endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
                endpoints.MapHealthChecks("/health", new HealthCheckOptions()
                {
                    Predicate = _ => true,
                    ResponseWriter = UIResponseWriter.
                    WriteHealthCheckUIResponse
                });
                endpoints.MapHealthChecksUI();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

If we take the following example IP where the app is hosted `1.1.1.1:80` is there some setting I'm supposed to set in **Startup.cs** or anywhere else in order to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution.
Basically add the host ip and port infront of the `/health` in the `AddHealthCheckEndpoint` override. Remember `http` and `https` are not interchangeable so use the correct one based on what you configured in IIS.

```
            services.AddHealthChecksUI(opt =>
            {
                opt.SetEvaluationTimeInSeconds(5); //time in seconds between check    
                opt.MaximumHistoryEntriesPerEndpoint(60); //maximum history of checks    
                opt.SetApiMaxActiveRequests(1); //api requests concurrency    
                opt.AddHealthCheckEndpoint("Ajua API", "http://1.1.1.1:80/health"); //map health check api    
            }).AddInMemoryStorage();
```